# Remote access to Apache Server

Tags: apache, dns, server, dyndns, noip

I have a LAMP server used to remotely access a MySQL database (through a dynamic DNS service). Until yesterday, everything was working fine. Here is what I checked so far, without any success (I keep receiving a timeout error when trying to access remotely the server):

- Dynamic DNS service is ON on my router, updated for the correct external-IP address (using NoIP ddns.net).
- The server is working just fine locally on 192.168.0.24 and I can access the MySQL database from it.
- Ports forwarding is set correctly
- Firewall at the router level has been temporarily disabled

Here's my Apache ports.conf file:

> ```
>     Listen 80
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
>     ServerName www.example.com
>
>     # Other directives here
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

SharkWire gives me this output on the failed request :

533 15.633088 192.168.0.14 79.***.***.*** TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 27536 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1 –

** Details of the SharkWire failed Request here: [http://imgur.com/a/KtGuY](https://imgur.com/a/KtGuY) **

Edit: I am not able to connect using the external IP (instead of the DynDNS address) either, so the problem seems to be on the server side more than on the IP resolution side.

I have no idea what to check anymore and would welcome any advice/idea.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks Joni for your answer, I receive a '408: Timeout-error' when trying to connect to the server remotely.

Comment: That's a timeout for sending a request. Sounds like you manage to establish a connection to the server, but the HTTP request does not get through. Something could be wrong with network or firewall settings on the server. Try using wireshark or tcpdump to see what happens with the request.

Comment: WireShark gives me the following error :  533 15.633088 192.168.0.14 79.***.***.*** TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 27536 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is therefore off-topic for StackOverflow. It would be on-topic, and would have a much better chance of getting answered, if it was submitted to the ServerFault site at http://serverfault.com/  FWIW I see no problem with that TCP packet.  The interesting thing is what happens next: how does the server _respond_ to that packet?  Please add that information when you move the question to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to connect to your Apache server, are you connected on the same router ? I had a similar problem. And the problem was that the adress could only be access from another router (which seems logical).

Answer (score 0):

I would put a folder named html and inside that a folder named img in the folder named example1 and land the page called index there.